# Using the universal property of spaces

Tags: ct.category-theory, infinity-categories

The $\infty$-category of spaces has the following properties:

1. It is the $\infty$-category obtained from the (ordinary) category of finite sets by freely adding sifted colimits. (See e.g. Cesnavicius-Scholze https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.10932 §5.1 for a review of this notion and for pointers to Lurie's HTT where this is proven.)
2. (As Tim Campion points out in a comment, another characterization, also in HTT): Spaces are obtained by freely adding arbitrary colimits to the category $\{*\}$.

Can either of these characterizations be used (ideally without referring to the model of quasi-categories) to show other properties, such as:

- that colimits in spaces are universal (proven by Lurie in HTT Lemma 6.1.3.14)?
- possibly even that $Cat_\infty$ is generated by (the compact objects) $*$ and $\Delta^1$?

Comment: Even more fundamental than the sifted-cocompletion statement is the fact that $Spaces$ is the free cocomplete $\infty$-category on an object, and more generally that $Psh(C)$ is the free cocomplete $\infty$-category on $C$ (HTT 5.1.5.6). Would you be interested in proofs starting from these facts? Also I find it ironic that you're trying to avoid quasicategories as a model specifically -- Lurie's proof of 6.1.3.14 constructs an explicit right adjoint to base change at the level of model categories, so if anything is more tied to the "simplicial category" model than the quasicategory model.

Comment: Also, I'd be careful about the statement about $Cat_\infty$ -- what exactly do you mean by "compactly generated by particular objects"? It's true that $Cat_\infty$ is generated under colimits by $\ast$ and $\Delta[1]$. But I'm pretty sure that $\{\ast,\Delta[1]\}$ is not a _dense_ generator for $Cat_\infty$ -- a natural way to fix that would be to include $\Delta[n]$ for all $n$. And in order to find $\mathcal C \subseteq Cat_\infty$ such that $Cat_\infty = Ind(\mathcal C)$, you need to include all $\infty$-categories generated under finite colimits by $\ast$ and $\Delta[1]$.

Comment: That's an intriguing question ! It is a general fact that freely added colimits are Van Kampen colimits (universal and effective)... but the proof of that I know relies on the fact that these colimits are Van Kampen in the $\infty$-category of spaces in the first place... (and it fails if you look at categories enriched in something where colimits are not van Kampen...)

Comment: @TimCampion: yes, if there is a proof starting from the characterization by means of freely adding colimits, this would also be interesting to see. I have added this to the question. And concerning $Cat_\infty$ my wording was indeed a bit sloppy, I've adjusted the question slightly.

Comment: @SimonHenry: interesting comment - can you name a reference for the fact you mention?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Also when I talk about the fact that "freely added colimits are van Kampen" I'm rather talking about of bunch of example of more precise result in that direction, for example the coproduct completion of a finite limite category is extensive (=van Kampen coproduct), the completion under all colimits of a finite limit infinity-category has all van Kampen colimits, etc etc... each time it is proved by using that these free cocompletion can be described as a full subcategory of a presheaf category, and that colimits in presheaf category are van Kampen because they are in spaces.

Comment: @SimonHenry The fact that colimits are van Kampen is a descent property, but the question just asks about universality of colimits, which is basically just the fact that $Spaces$ is locally cartesian closed. This should be easier, I think.

Comment: @TimCampion Feel free to replace Van Kampen by "universal" in all my comments above, as far as I'm concerned it does not change my point. I feel the question is more interesting with Van Kampen than with universal though, given that freely added colimits are always Van Kampen.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a "model-independent" proof that colimits in $Spaces$ are universal. Of course, the ingredients going into the proof may have model-dependent proofs.

**Fact:** Colimits in $Spaces$ are universal.

**Proof:** We want to show that for any map of spaces $f: Y \to X$, the pullback functor $$f^\ast: Spaces_{/X} \to Spaces_{/Y}$$ preserves colimits. We may view $X,Y$ as $\infty$-categories which happen to be $\infty$-groupoids and $f: Y \to X$ as a functor between them. By straightening / unstraightening, the functor $f^\ast :Spaces_{/X} \to Spaces_{/Y}$ is identitified with the "precompose $f$" functor $$f^\ast: Psh(X) \to Psh(Y)$$ Now, $Psh(X),Psh(Y)$ are functor categories with values in the cocomplete category $Spaces$. So colimits are computed "objectwise" in these categories. That is, for $F: I \to Psh(X)$, we have $(\varinjlim_{i \in I} F(i))(x) = \varinjlim_{i \in I} (F(i)(x))$, and similarly in $Y$. From these formulas, it is immediate that precomposing $f$ preserves colimits. That is, we have $$(\varinjlim_{i \in I} f^\ast F(i))(y) = \varinjlim_{i \in I} F(i)(f(y)) = \varinjlim_{i \in I} (f^\ast F(i))(y)$$ as desired.

---

This proof doesn't precisely use the universal property of $Psh(X),Psh(Y)$ of freely adding colimits, but perhaps it could be tweaked to do so.